# Show the key + values of a model within a foreach loop

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using ember 2.1 with ember-data and I'm trying to spit out the keys and values in the ember-data object without having to specify each column individually.

For example:

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |row|}}
      <li>{{row}} <small>{{moment-from-now row.createdAt}}</small></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

So where it says {{row}} which returns the full object "client@model:modelName::ember939:1". I don't want to have to say {{row.name}} but rather spit out each key and value for each row in the model.

The whole point is to give the component any data from any model, and it will show all the information correctly without having to specify the field names for every db table.

Comment: what do you mean by *the full object `""`*? If I understand you correctly, you want to display all key:value pairs for your `row` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `each-in` combined with array of attributes of model. I think there should be some better way of getting `attributes` without using private properties (maybe in controller?), because it is discouraged. However, it's working:

```
<ul>
    {{#each model as |row|}}
      {{#each-in row._internalModel._data as |key value|}}
        <li>{{key}} : {{value}}</li>
      {{/each-in}}
      <hr/>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nipoqajoge/3/edit?html,js,output)

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This works well. Really, I don't want to do it in a controller as it's a component, so I don't want any repetition. I'd rather handle it all here.

This seems to have me started though, so thanks :)

Comment: You could improve it by getting attributes property of static model type and using it instead of `row._internalModel._data`, and then `{{get row value}}` instead of `{{value}}`.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at this earlier http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_attributes But couldn't figure out how to implement it inside my component.js